# Is it possible to simulate a SmtpFailedRecipientException/SmtpFailedRecipientsException from an SMTP in localhost?

Tags: c#

I'm sending mail using `SmtpClient.Send()`. One of the exceptions that can be caught is the `SmtpFailedRecipientException` or `SmtpFailedRecipientsException`

I tried putting in a bogus email address such as foo@bar.com, the exception won't be thrown. I'm using 127.0.0.1 as my SmtpClient.

Is it possible to mock a `SmtpFailedRecipientException`?

Comment: Why don't you just manually throw a SmtpFailedRecipientException

Comment: I could do that. But that exception isn't necessarily thrown by all SMTPs, for example Google. I want to understand how SMTPs throw that back.

Comment: Well if your saying that each different provider may have different results then how do you expect to mock an unknown behavior?

Comment: SMTPs are configurable aren't they? It's completely legitimate for an SMTP provider to say, hey, if this email doesn't exist, we are going to throw this exception at you. Why would the exception be expected to be caught if there was no way to expect it from outside code?